# Enable Zip PHP extension on AWS EC2

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, zip, moodle

I'm trying to use EBS to set up a Moodle 3.1 platform on AWS EBS. I've set up the environment, uploaded the moodle zip package which deploys correctly. I run through the **web installation**, connect to the db, but I get stuck at the pre-requisite checks with the **following error**:

> The **Zip PHP extension is now required** by Moodle, info-ZIP binaries or
>   PclZip library are not used anymore.

I'm not quite certain how to:

1. log into the EC2 instance that the EBS environment created
2. how to install the php extension once I'm in there

I've looked through the aws and moodle docs but they all have you ssh into an EC2 instance. I've logged into my other EC2 instances (not EBS) with putty, but I'm not sure how/which instance I need to SSH into to correct this error.  I also though that maybe the config settings for EBS - Zlib output compression: On/True would do the trick but that hasn't worked.

Anything else I could try?

Answer (score 7):

Simply type :

```
sudo yum install php-zip
sudo service httpd restart
```

Comment: For me, this worked on an **Amazon Linux 2** with **PHP 7.2**

Answer (score 1):

You can customize instance package using packages options.

```
packages: 
  yum:
    libmemcached: [] 
    ruby-devel: []
    gcc: []
  rpm:
    epel: http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
  rubygems: 
    chef: '0.10.2'
```

You can view an example here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-packages

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

First install pecl and then use following command

```
yum install php-pecl-zip
```